# Access an instance from a function outside of the object constructor

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, object

I have a problem I can't understand after a lot of attempts to solve it.

To help you understand, there are 2 classes (Game and Board), and a third file with the jQuery keypress controls. Game is about the logic of the game, and Board about the display.

Here is a part of the code I hope sufficient to understand.

```
// GAME CLASS
function Game(width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;

  this.forbiddenPosition = [];

  this.chartBoard = this.resetBoard();

  this.generateGame();
}

Game.prototype.generateGame = function () {
  this.player1 = new Player("Joueur 1", 100, dagger);
  this.player2 = new Player("Joueur 2", 100, dagger);
  const playerArray = [this.player1, this.player2];
}

Game.prototype.getPlayer1 = function () {
  return this.player1;
};

Game.prototype.getPlayer2 = function () {
  return this.player2;
};
Game.prototype.switchTurn = function (player1, player2) {

  console.log(player1);
  console.log(player2);
};

// BOARD CLASS
const ctx = $('#board').get(0).getContext('2d');

function Board (width, height) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.game = new Game(this.width, this.height);

  this.displayInfoPlayers(this.game.getPlayer1(), this.game.getPlayer2());
}


Board.prototype.displayInfoPlayers = function (player1, player2) {
  $('.canvas-side__left').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('.canvas-side__right').css('visibility', 'visible');
  $('.canvas-side__left').addClass('animated slideInLeft');
  $('.canvas-side__right').addClass('animated slideInRight');

  $(".canvas-side__left").html("<h2 class='canvas-side--title'>" + player1.name + "</h2><p class='canvas-side--health'>" + player1.health + "</p><p class='canvas-side--health'>" + player1.weapon.name + "</p>");

  $(".canvas-side__right").html("<h2 class='canvas-side--title'>" + player2.name + "</h2><p class='canvas-side--health'>" + player2.health + "</p><p class='canvas-side--health'>" + player2.weapon.name + "</p>");
};

// CONTROL
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
  if (e.which == 13) {
    Game.prototype.switchTurn(Game.prototype.getPlayer1(), Game.prototype.getPlayer2());
    e.stopPropagation();
  }
});
```

Board class is linked to Game class and so uses this. The control using jQuery code are in a third file and not into a class.

When I press Enter, I get undefined for player1 and 2. I tried different ways to call the getter functions and nothing works. I also tried to put the controls inside the Game file and still nothing.

I get either undefined or getPlayer1() is not a function.

I am looking for a way to call these getter functions from everywhere so I can use player1 and 2 which I need to move on the board.

Comment: `Game.prototype.getPlayer1()` will return `undefined` because `this` refers to `Game.prototype` not an instance of `Game`. You need to create an instance of `Game` using the new operator like `const game = new Game()` and then run `game.getPlayer1()` etc

Comment: @adiga But the function returns this.player1. This is why I don't understand the problem.

Comment: As I mentioned in the previous comment, `this` refers to `Game.prototype` when you call `Game.prototype.getPlayer1()`. And there is no `player1` property inside `Game.prototype`. It only exists on `Game` objects created using the [new operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new). It should probably be: `const game = new Game(); game.getPlayer1()`

Comment: @adiga It works thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues there.

1. The keypress event handler is using `Game.prototype`, not an instance of `Game`. You want to be using an instance of `Game` you've created and stored somewhere. `Game.prototype` doesn't have the `player1` and `player2` properties. They're added to instances of `Game` by the `Game` constructor. Nothing ever adds them to `Game.prototype` (which is correct, they shouldn't be on the prototype).
2. There's no need for `getPlayer1`, etc. You can directly access `player1` and `player2`. (It's *possible* to make `player1` and `player2` private and only provide accessors for them, but it's a bit complicated at the moment and probably not something you want to take on yet.)
3. Within `Game` methods, you need to consistently use `this.player1` and `this.player2`, don't pass the players around.
4. It seems odd for `Board` to create an instance of `Game`. It seems like it should be the other way around.

I suggest stepping back from this task and trying something simpler first (like creating a class, an instance of the class, and using that instance in an event handler), then incrementally adding complexity and making sure at each stage you're clear on what's happening. As you go, you may have more specific questions, which you can post on SO (after thorough research, etc.).

Comment: Thanks.

So getPlayer1 is useless for now if I don't make player1 and player2 private?
I try to work in a functional way but I'm still learning.

I created an instance of Game in Board because the display is waiting for changes in Game (logic of the game), and only display it.

Comment: @GrégoryHuyghe - Right, with what you have now, `player1` and `getPlayer1` have the same visibility, so... (I should note that if you're trying to work in a functional programming way, you probably wouldn't use constructor functions and `new` at all.)

Comment: What should I use instead of constructors and new operator? There is no class in functional programming?

Comment: @GrégoryHuyghe - I suggest an FP primer or tutorial. SO comments aren't the place to write one, and I'm not qualified to do so in any case. :-) (My knowledge of FP is only minor.) My impression is that no, you wouldn't use JavaScript's constructor-function-and-`new` pattern when writing FP JavaScript; instead, I think you build objects directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this and it should work. Essentially, you prototype the function you're trying to access which is not declared until after the constructor.

```
class Test {
  constructor() {
    this.five = Test.prototype.getFive();
  }

  getFive() {
    return 5;
  }
}

let test = new Test();
console.log(test.five); // Returns 5
```